# "Passing arguments to subroutine"-question?

Tags: perl, reference, argument-passing, subroutine

Is routine2 ok too or shouldn't I do this? (I don't need a copy of @list in the subroutine)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.012;
use warnings;
my @list = 0 .. 9;


sub routine1 {
    my $list = shift;
    for (@$list) { $_++ };
    return $list
}
my $l = routine1( \@list );
say "@$l";


sub routine2 {
    for (@list) { $_++ };
}
routine2();
say "@list";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it works for you, then it's ok too. But the first sub can do the job for any array you pass to it which makes it more general.

P.S. Remember that `@_` contains aliases for the parameters passed to the function. So you could also use this:

```
sub increment { $_++ for @_ }
increment(@list);
```

Comment: +1 but my answer (prototype to `(\@)`) could also be useful (like if the function had to take more parameters later).

Comment: @sid_com: Is this subroutine your performance bottleneck? Premature optimization is the root of all evil ;)

Comment: It's more the combination: it's not the common way and it's not faster then the common way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about making the syntax look nice, try this:

```
sub routine3 (\@) {
  for (@{$_[0]}) { $_++ }
}

my @list = (0 .. 9);
routine3(@list);
say "@list"; # prints 1 .. 10
```

This declares `routine3` with a prototype - it takes an array argument by reference. So `$_[0]` is a reference to `@list`, no rather unsightly `\` needed by the caller. (Some people discourage prototypes, so take this as you will. I like them.)

But unless this is a simplification for what your actual routine does, what I'd do is this:

```
my @list = 0 .. 9;
my @new_list = map { $_ + 1 } @list;
say "@new_list";
```

Unless `routine` is actually really complicated, and it's vital somehow that you modify the original array, I'd just use `map`. Especially with `map`, you can plug in a subroutine:

```
sub complex_operation { ... }

my @new_list = map { complex_operation($_) } @list;
```

Of course, you could prototype `complex_operation` with `(_)` and then just write `map(complex_operation, @list);` but I like the bracket-syntax personally.

Comment: I don't need prototypes and my examples are simplifications.

Comment: @sid_com - If you already know what you do and don't need, why are you asking us? If you use option 1, I would use the prototype and make the calling code look nicer just as a personal preference, but otherwise I believe they're the same code. (Although since you're modifying the array you don't really need to return it.)

Comment: To make the "dislike prototypes" case: Be aware that this approach would require you to pass *exactly one array* - not an arbitrary list - to the sub. The prototype would, for example, prevent you from doing `routine3($foo, $bar, $baz)` or `routine3(@first, @second)`. You would instead have to create a temp array, place all your values in it, pass that, and then return the results to the original variables: `my @temp = ($foo, $bar, $baz); routine3(@temp); ($foo, $bar, $baz) = @temp;`

Comment: When passing by reference the "\@array" doesn't bother me much, its more the dereferencing in the subroutine - it could be more often and I have to think more.

Comment: @sid_com - I always prefer to have a clean syntax in calling code, because we make functions to call them more than to look at their internal code, so I don't usually care what horrid syntax goes on inside them. But I can see why you don't like all the dereferencing.